# SharePoint server is not working

Tags: sharepoint-server

### Question

My SharePoint server 2016 is not working. How I can fixed this issue without losing my sites

### Image

[image]

### Image

[image]

Comment: have you try to restart the app pool?

Comment: are you tried to set the credential again of your service account ? are you face this issue only when you tried to create a site ?! what's the farm build number?

Comment: I restart my pool and error remains after set the credential too.

Comment: what you will see if browse the http://jarvis ?

Comment: same service unavailable 503 errror

Comment: Stop the IIS server and then browse the sites and you will get 503 Error? then restart the server

Answer (score 1):

In IIS, Make sure that the Application pool of your SharePoint web application is started,

- if not started try to start it.
- if started then stopped, try to provide the credential again of your application pool identity.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

HTTP error 503 means the app pool is not working. Go to Server and check the App Pool for the Web app. If it is stop then start it.